# How to create button with icon using react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to create button like this:

[image]

using react-native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to answer this question, depending on what else you have going on in your application. The one thing I've found that is important when styling in React Native is understanding the FlexBox properties, which will allow you to do pretty much any layout you can imagine once you learn them.

I've gone ahead and set up a sample project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/yNKoGA) with a button similar to the one above implemented in code, and I've also posted the code below. Note that there are a ton of ways to achieve this, this is just one of the many ways.

https://rnplay.org/apps/yNKoGA

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#ededed" style={{borderRadius:10, height:60, borderWidth:1, marginLeft:80, marginRight:80}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', }}>
        <View>
            <Image style={{marginTop:9, marginLeft:4,width:40, height:40}} source={{uri: 'http://www.iconpng.com/png/iconographicons/basketball19.png'}} />
        </View>
        <Text style={{ fontSize:20, marginLeft:10, marginTop:16 }}>Login</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: The only thing I would add to that you don't need a separate view for the flow direction. You can define this directly on the TouchableHighlight wrapper view together with the borderRadius etc. Neither do you need a View to wrap the Image. And it usually makes sense to use "alignItems: 'center'" to vertically center image and text in the button.